Eigenvalue algorithms for small matrices
I want to write a numerical library (in C++) that provides the eigenvalues of small matrices ($3\times3$–$20\times20$) for my line of work.
I read a little bit of literature and the consensus is basically that for symmetric matrices using a householder transformation to get them into Hessenberg form, for which there exist efficient algorithms, is the most efficient way to get all the eigenvalues. Also, using a Schur decomposition should be feasible.
But what efficient algorithms are out there for non-symmetric small matrices? Are there better ways than just using QR? Or what can be specifically improved in a shifted QR algorithm to make it more efficient for small matrices? Are there algorithms (thinking about something like the power method) that are extremely efficient for small matrices when we're just interested in one eigenvalue?
I found Eigenvalues of Small Matrices question which strongly suggests that calculating the roots of the characteristic polynomial doesn't cut it even for small matrices (which was to be expected).
Unfortunately, I haven't found a post that deals with non-symmetric matrices.

For symmetric matrices, you'd use a tridiagonal form, not a Hessenberg form, that is for non-symmetric problems.

The QR algorithm (aka Francis's algorithm) with shifts is the standard approach.

I definitely agree that using LAPACK (reference Netlib or a vendor-optimized variant) is a good initial choice. You'll get numerically stable Housholder reductions inside the QR method with handling of tricky corner cases (non-symmetric eigenvectors are inherently unstable). But your question also suggests that you might want to look at other places. Unfortunately, Eigen does not have non-symmetric case but it would've been a great match for your C++ code with expression templates to optimization small matrix cases. If you choose to implement a simple power method then Eigen may be worth a look to get your code inlined for the small dimensions. Keep in mind that the power method likes well separated eigenvalues and tends to be poor in delivering orthogonal eigenvectors. Yousef Saad books are always a good place to start (disregard "large problems" in the title and focus on the numerical issues to avoid).
Correction: I missed the non-symmetric eigensolvers in Eigen 3.4: real and complex. They're based on JAMA which in turn results in EISPACK. This may mean slower code for large matrices but may do just fine for the smaller ones.

Can you please elaborate waht you mean by "Eigen does not have non-symmetric case"? AFAIK, libeigen finds eigenvalues for unsymmetric matrices, too.

Yes, you're correct. I took a second look at their "catalogue" page and, even though some information is missing, clicking through reveals that Eigen 3.4 can compute eigenvalues of non-symmetric matrices in both real and complex domains.

For non-symmetric matrices, you won't beat the QR algorithm. It is very robust and reasonably fast. That being said, there are significant gains to be made in the implementation side.
LAPACK is optimized for large matrices. Instead of optimizing every single operation, it accumulates many of the small householder reflectors used in the algorithm into a larger orthogonal matrix and applies it using a matrix-matrix multiplication. Those matrix-matrix multiplications are implemented very efficiently and if the matrix is large enough, you can neglect all the other operations because almost all the flops are inside the matrix-matrix multiplications. But that reasoning does not apply for small matrices.
I can think of a few optimizations:

Keep very small matrices loaded in the registers.
Optimize the Reflector/Rotation routine. The QR algorithm needs to calculate a Givens rotation or a Householder reflector $O(n^2)$ times. This is usually negligible compared to the total $O(n^3)$ cost, but if $n$ is small it can become dominant. Instead of calculating $\sqrt{f^2 + g^2}$ and dividing by it, you can approximate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{f^2 + g^2}}$ directly using special instructions. That's only an approximation so you'll need to refine it using a newton step (or 2 for double precision), but that should still be faster.
Vectorization using AVX intrinsics, the QR algorithm switches between operations on columns and operations on rows. This is quite difficult to vectorize and your compiler is unlikely to do it optimally. While you're at it, you can also vectorize the calculation of the orthogonal transformations.
Use communication avoiding techniques, like combining the application of several rotations/reflectors.

Keep in mind that these are advanced techniques and if not done properly they can make the code slower. Or worse, make the code less accurate in ways that are hard to predict. I agree with the other answers that LAPACK or another library are probably your best bet.

What do you mean by $\sqrt{f^2+g^2}$? Do they appear in the calculation of the rotation parameters $c$ and $s$ when using given rotations?

Yes, they appear when calculating the Givens rotations, but similar optimizations are likely possible for reflectors.

You cannot beat the algorithms that are implemented in the widely used LAPACK library. You will spend weeks or months reading up on the best algorithms, implementing them, and optimizing them, and get something that is still less robust, less accurate, and slower than what LAPACK has. Use LAPACK.

lapack and blas have significant overhead that absolutely is possible to beat for small matrices

For $3\times 3$, I will believe this. For $20\times 20$, I'm doubtful.
